# Excel: Resetting table based on day

Tags: excel

I'm gonna start by saying that I am not that experienced in excel and whatnot but I can manage with some instructions although I ran into a bit of a problem.
So, I've got a timesheet that supposedly tracks the start time, end time, project name and all those things, mind you, not a weekly timesheet, but a daily timesheet. I also have a row above all those columns showing the date and like I said, I'm not that experienced, I resorted to a drop down list with each day and month. 
Now, the problem is, instead of copying the same table over and over again in a sheet, I want instead, whenever I change the date from the drop down list, all the cells that include the start time, end time, project name etc. to "reset" and likewise whenever I go back to a date that I've added data previously, to appear.

Is there any way in which I can do this ? Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like you need a filter

Comment: You may need INDEX+MATCH but really without seeing some sample data with expected result it is hard to explain how you can utilise these functions.

Comment: I see, I will try posting a link to the worksheet once I get to work tomorrow morning where I have the file.